# Reading password protected excel using epplus in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, epplus

I am downloading the excel file with password using epplus library. The downloading part is working fine.

```
public ActionResult DownloadExcel()
{

string sFileName = string.Empty;

using (ExcelPackage package = projectBL.DownloadExcel(ID, id1, id3, id4, id5))
   {
     System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = package.File.Name,
        };

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

        return File(package.GetAsByteArray("password"), "application/vndopenxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

    }
}
```

But whenever I am trying to upload this password protected file it is giving me below error

> The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted,
>   please supply the password in the constructor.

So, I have resolved the above error my providing the required password to read the file. Below is the code for the same.

```
public ActionResult UploadExcel()
{
  if (Request.Form.Files != null && Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
   {
     var fileObject = Request.Form.Files[0];

     string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(fileObject.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

     var Stream = fileObject.OpenReadStream();

     ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(Stream,"password");

     projectBL.SaveData(package);

     return Json("Records Saved Succesfully.");
    }
}
```

However, after providing the password still I am not able to read/upload the excel file due to below error

> The stream must be read/write

So my question is how can i read the password protected file using Stream. I am using this code in web api.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: I'm no expert, but the 'var stream = fileObject.OpenreadStream()' is doing as it says, opening a read only stream, where as the 'new ExcelPackage(Stream, "password");' wants a read/write stream. Could you change it to 'var stream = fileObject.OpenStream()' instead? I'm not sure what type it is but maybe it holds a method similar to that.

Comment: @DubDub No, there is only one method which reads the file, no other method available

Comment: What is the type of fileObject?

Comment: @DubDub its IFormFile which of type interface

Comment: If you saved the file, you could then use the method that the below answer suggested.
If you can't, then you're going to want to use the fileObject.CopyTo() method, which will copy the contents of that file to a stream.Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.7.2 

I'd perhaps suggest trying a few different ones, the memory stream may be the approach you want to take, so create a local MemorySteam, then call fileObject.CopyTo(MemoryStream), then try create the Excel package with that stream.

Comment: @DubDub Thanks for the solution.. It worked !

Comment: Glad to hear, although it wasn't so much a solution than a few tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it a XLS or XLSX file?  EPplus cannot works with XLS files.

Here how I simply do with EPPLUS :

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(fileName), "password"))
{}
```

Comment: I already tried with this one. The problem is if I use FileInfo class, then the file is not available. As i am uploading the file from local path, thats why I have used stream to read the file. The api is hosted on azure.

Answer (score 3):

When I tried to upload excel file and it shown the code error for 
"The file is not an valid Package file. If the file is encrypted, please supply the password in the constructor".

But my excel file was not encrypted and also was not password protected.

I find out a solution by using try catch like I just opened my excel file and then try to save that file from .xls to .xlsx format.

After doing this, file upload was successful and EPPlus dll did not give any error and working well!